# Does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{k}} (-1)^k$ converge faster than $e^{-\sqrt{k}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{k}} (-1)^k$ converge faster than $e^{-\sqrt{k}}$? In particular, is

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} e^{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k=N}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{k}} (-1)^k=0?
$$

I know that when the $\sqrt{k}$ and $\sqrt{N}$ are replaced with $k$ and $N$ the expression in the limit oscillates around $0$ alongside the parity of $N$. The square root effectively makes the sign of that summand wiggle faster, so I suspect that the extra cancellation makes the series converge faster.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't is quite trivial that $e^{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k\geq N}e^{-\sqrt{k}}(-1)^k$ behaves like $(-1)^N$, hence the given limit does not exist?

Comment: It might well be true, but I don't think it's trivial. Note that the difference between $e^{-\sqrt N}(-1)^N$ and $e^{-\sqrt{N+1}}(-1)^{N+1}$ is about $e^{-\sqrt N}/2\sqrt N$ in absolute value by the mean value theorem; so one will have to account for many terms in the sum, not just the first one.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{ e^{\sqrt{N}}}{ \sum_{k=N}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{k}} (-1)^k}=0?
$$

Comment: @Mathily: that is blatantly wrong, since the numerator is huge and the denominator rather small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k\geq N}e^{-\sqrt{k}}(-1)^k = (-1)^N \sum_{h\geq 0}(-1)^h \exp\left(-\frac{h}{\sqrt{N+h}+\sqrt{N}}\right) $$
is well-approximated by
$$ (-1)^N\sum_{h\geq 0}(-1)^h \exp\left(-\frac{h}{2\sqrt{N}}\right) = \frac{(-1)^N}{1+\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}}\right)}$$
hence the given limit does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I wouldn't have thought of that first step with the difference of squares.

Comment: @Lichko: you're welcome. That "rationalization" trick is pretty useful in dealing with differences of square roots. You may use it, for instance, for proving that $$-2\sqrt{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ has a finite limit as $N\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of.  Let $S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^ke^{-\sqrt{k}}$.  Then a basic error bound on partial sums of alternating series tells us
$$\left|S-\sum_{k=0}^N (-1)^ke^{-\sqrt{k}}\right|<\left|(-1)^{N+1}e^{-\sqrt{N+1}}\right|=e^{-\sqrt{N+1}}$$
And we know that $L=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} e^{-\sqrt{k}}=0 $, so the distance for $k=N$  to the limit is $\left|L-e^{-\sqrt{N}}\right|=e^{-\sqrt{N}}$.

So, since $e^{-\sqrt{N}}>e^{-\sqrt{N+1}}$, we have that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^ke^{-\sqrt{k}}$ converges faster in that it is always closer to its limit.  However, often 'converges faster than' is meant about the ratio of their closeness to their limits going to 0, this doesn't support such a claim, though it could be true.

Comment: The series $\sum_{k\geq 0}e^{-\sqrt{k}}$ is yet fast-converging since the main term decays really fast. So the introduction of alternating signs in $\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k e^{-\sqrt{k}}$ does not really improve the speed of convergence, as it happens in $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}\mapsto\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$, where the main term exhibits a polynomial decay.

Comment: Graphically we can confirm that $\sum_{k\ \geq\ 0}\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{k}}$ converges faster than the 'alternating' one.

Comment: @FelixMarin The absolute percent errors between the partial sums and the full series of the alternating series seem to be lower than those of the non-alternating series.